# unable to access angular scope variable outside from javascript after gulp build

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am using `gulp` to develop `angular` app.
If I run my app using `gulp serve` I can access my `scope` from outside, I can run this code in chrome console successfully

`angular.element("html[ng-app='admin']").scope().myVariable`

But If I run `gulp build` and deploy `dist` folder to my web server I am not able to get controllers scope variable.
How is it possible?

There is my `gulp` (default from yeoman generator)

```
gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp,     '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
var partialsInjectOptions = {
starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
addRootSlash: false
};

var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html');
var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');
var assets;

 return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
.pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
.pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
.pipe($.rev())
.pipe(jsFilter)
.pipe($.ngAnnotate())
 // .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense  })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
  .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
.pipe(cssFilter)
.pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
.pipe($.csso())
.pipe(cssFilter.restore())
.pipe(assets.restore())
.pipe($.useref())
.pipe($.revReplace())
.pipe(htmlFilter)
//.pipe($.minifyHtml({
//  empty: true,
//  spare: true,
//  quotes: true,
//  conditionals: true
//}))
.pipe(htmlFilter.restore())
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
.pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true  }));
});
```

EDIT:
There is result of evaluation of

`angular.element("html[ng-app='admin']").scope()`

in development mode(gulp serve)

```
 $$ChildScope: null
 $$childHead: null
 $$childTail: null
 $$listenerCount: Object
 $$listeners: Object
 $$nextSibling: null
 $$prevSibling: null
 $$watchers: null
 $$watchersCount: 0
 $id: 3
 $parent: Scope
```

And there is same but in production(gulp build)

```
  $$ChildScope: ChildScope()
  $$childHead: ChildScope
 $$childTail: ChildScope
 $$listenerCount: Object
 $$listeners: Object
 $$nextSibling: null
 $$prevSibling: null
 $$watchers: Array[3]
 $$watchersCount: 22
 $id: 3
 $parent: Scope
 main: Object
 setData: (data)
```

Iam interesting in **main** object(controllers variable).

EDIT2:
I also tried `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();` but with the same result.

Comment: `I am not able to get controllers scope variable` - what happens when you tries?

Comment: I edited my original question. I also investigated parent,root scope but Iam not able to find property **main**.

Answer (score 0):

Do you or one of gulp plugins have disabled it somewhere?

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}])
```

Check: [Disabling Debug Data in AngularJS application](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production)
If that's the problem, running in console `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();` should help.

Another thing to check - if you're using javascript code minification in gulp then maybe some of the dependancy injection statements are being missed. I mean declaration should include correct DI items naming, like this:

```
var controllerFunction = function($scope, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
    //do stuff
}

angular.module('myApp.myModule')
.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', controllerFunction]);
```

Comment: I have set correctly `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);` If I disable this feature Iam not even able to get  scope .I got undefind instead of empty scope by calling : `angular.element("html[ng-app='admin']").scope()`

Comment: I turned off mimification and 'uglification' in gulp(See commented lines in my original question). Iam also using ngInject to DI my dependencies. I inject my dependencies as follows: `angular
  .module('xx.module')
  .factory('MyService', myService);

/* @ngInject */
function myService($resource,coreConfig) {`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in my controller. I had an js error in my controller causing my controller was not initialized properly and scope was empty.
Thanks for your help.